# Pupeteer with very large PDF not waiting until loaded

Tags: handlebars.js, puppeteer

Problem: Pupeteer generates a PDF when only about 5% of my data is there.

I'm using puppeteer to pass about 3000 lines of text to a handlebars HTML template I'm then trying to use puppeteer to print a PDF from.  Had this working earlier today but a Git fiasco made me roll back and now I cant seem to generate a pdf longer than 3.5 pages (earlier this week it was up to about 90).

I'm thinking this has to do with the following:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
        headless: true
    });

    var page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, {
        waitUntil:'load'. <------ (i've also tried networkidle0 and networkidle2)
    });


    await page.pdf(options);
    await browser.close()
```

Heres the template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PDF</title>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

<body>
    <ul id="script">
        {{#each this}}
        <li class={{category}}>{{text}}</li>
        {{/each}}

    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

My data is an array of 3300 objects and I know it's getting where it needs to.  Is there anyway to set a static timeout for Puppeteer?   I realize this is a lot of data but am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The `waitUntil:'load'` goto parameter is the default, you don't need to set it, while the `networkidle0` and `networkidle2` options are waiting for network connections to be finished: as you don't have any of these as it is a plain HTML markup it neither helps to wait until it is populated with your desired data. I would rather suggest you to use `domcontentloaded` if you want to use waitUntil. You can check what are the exact differences between them in the [docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options).

**I.) Your problem can be solved with a static timeout, it is called [`page.waitFor`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args).** If you are sure all data will be in the pdf in a certain time then you can set a static timeout, e.g. 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds) before the pdf generation.

```js
await page.waitFor(3000);
await page.pdf(options);
```

---

**II.) If you can access the very last `text` value of each object, you could also wait for the content to be appeared.** But it will only work if you have unique content for each `<li>` element.

```js
const veryLastItemText = options[options.length - 1].text // if "options" is an array with "category" and "text" property names inside

await page.waitForXPath(`//li[contains(text(), "${veryLastItemText}")]`);
await page.pdf(options);
```

Comment: hitting timeout -   await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, {
  waitUntil:'load'
 });
 
 await page.waitForXPath(`//li[contains(text(), "${lastItem}")]`).     Last item has the proper values and should be in its own ,<li> , do i have it in the right order?

Comment: Yeah, it seems the element does not rendered to the page, so it results in a timeout. Normally a template genereation shouldn't take that long so the problem will be something else. See if the Data URI limitation is causing the issue, I've added a possible solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492393/passing-very-long-url-to-puppeteer-is-there-a-better-way/62496431#62496431

Comment: I think it has to do with length of the URL but not sure how to fix

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, see a possible solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496431/12412595