# Passing very long url to Puppeteer - is there a better way?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, url-parameters

So a git issue had me roll back about two weeks of work -

Im currently trying to pass an array of about 3300 string to a handlebars template then trying to print that as a pdf - my issue is I'm pretty sure my pupepteer URL is being cut off at 3000 characters.  Im at a loss for a workaround.

```
 <<<< my data logs as -----> Array(3330) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, …] >>>

 var templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.cwd(), 'template.html'), 'utf8');
    var template = handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
    var html = template(data);

await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, {
        waitFor:10000
    });
```

before my git meltdown I was printing out 90 page PDF's and I just cant figure out what I did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Your problem seems to be the [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) length limitation. It is **2MB** in case of [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/security/url_display_guidelines/url_display_guidelines.md#url-length). So if your `html` exceeds the limit it will be trimmed or even not rendered at all.

I suggest to use [`page.setContent`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagesetcontenthtml-options) with the same content as it has no upper limit.

### Example

*Note:* `setContent` needs a string as input, I've just copied the source of example.com.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('data:text/html,<h1>Template</h1>')
  await page.waitFor(2000)
  await page.setContent(
    '<!doctype html> <html> <head> <title>Example Domain</title> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> <style type="text/css"> body { background-color: #f0f0f2; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } div { width: 600px; margin: 5em auto; padding: 2em; background-color: #fdfdff; border-radius: 0.5em; box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02); } a:link, a:visited { color: #38488f; text-decoration: none; } @media (max-width: 700px) { div { margin: 0 auto; width: auto; } } </style> </head> <body> <div> <h1>Example Domain</h1> <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p> <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> </div> </body> </html>'
  )

  await page.pdf({ path: 'page.pdf' })

  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```